# How to check whether email id and password provided by user is correct?

Tags: java, email, imap

I am trying to validate the email id and password provided by user using imap java .I have written basic code which can connect to the account and download mails . but when the email id or password is incorrect it just give this error :

```
avax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Invalid credentials wu2mb53991170pac
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:474)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at mailchecker.main(mailchecker.java:19)
```

but what I want is just to check whether credentials are correct or not . For eg. if the credentials are correct program should print ok otherwise sorry or something like that...I am new to this so any idea how can I do this?

**EDIT:**
This is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {
        System.out.println("hi");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "<username>", "password");
        System.out.println(store);

        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
        for(Message message:messages) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("hi");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(2);
    } catch (javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("hi");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

when I put this it gives error .

```
error: exception AuthenticationFailedException has already been caught
```

What should I do?

Comment: Catch `AuthenticationFailedException` and write the error handling code in that block.

Comment: put it into try catch block if AuthenticationFailedException occure do what you want in your catch Block.

Comment: The reason you are getting `error: exception AuthenticationFailedException has already been caught` is because `AuthenticationFailedException` is a subclass of `MessagingException` which you have already caught

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your connection code in a `try-catch` block and catch `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`. For example:

```
try{
   //connect to mail server
    System.out.println("Ok");
}
catch(javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException e)
{
    //display connection error to the user, maybe allow them to retry
    System.out.println("Sorry your credentials are incorrect");
}
```

**EDIT:** The reason you are getting `error: exception AuthenticationFailedException has already been caught` is because `AuthenticationFailedException` is a child of `MessagingException` which you have already caught, see what happens when you change the order of the exceptions, i.e. catch `AuthenticationException` before `MessagingException`